# Where to source .profile in .bash_profile to install RVM in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cygwin, rvm

I am installing RVM on a windows machine using cygwin. I used the command is `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` to get RVM. But there is a problem. Please see the WARNING section in the output below and please help me to fix it.

```
# mspc,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/home/mspc/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile
```

Where do I put this line of code ?

Source code for the .bash_profile file -

```
# base-files version 4.2-3

# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash(1) for login shells.

# The latest version as installed by the Cygwin Setup program can
# always be found at /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.bash_profile

# Modifying /etc/skel/.bash_profile directly will prevent
# setup from updating it.

# The copy in your home directory (~/.bash_profile) is yours, please
# feel free to customise it to create a shell
# environment to your liking.  If you feel a change
# would be benifitial to all, please feel free to send
# a patch to the cygwin mailing list.

# User dependent .bash_profile file

# source the users bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
  source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi

# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi

# Set MANPATH so it includes users' private man if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/man" ]; then
#   MANPATH="${HOME}/man:${MANPATH}"
# fi

# Set INFOPATH so it includes users' private info if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/info" ]; then
#   INFOPATH="${HOME}/info:${INFOPATH}"
# fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that line anywhere in that file. The only question is whether that needs to be loaded before or after rvm is loaded and I can't answer that.

Whether you need to do this at all depends on whether there is anything in that file that you actually need as there very well might not be.